# Using VBA for insert and edit Mathtye equations in MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, mathtype

In **MS-Word**, almost we use **Mathtype** for inserting **equations**. When the MS-Word document contains several ones (Mathtype equation), and we have to use a **VBA macro coding** to change that preferences, for editing equations format, How can we do?

**This question is about changing Mathtype equation formats by VBA macro coding.**

Seems this is a complicate problem, because last, I asked issue here and no-one answered me, to now.
Please help me in this issue, if possible.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I needed to write a lot of vectors in my document so I recorded/wrote this :

```
Sub Vecteur()

    'change your selection to MathType

    Selection.OMaths.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    'change your selection to Vector type

    Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, wdOMathFunctionAcc).Acc _
        .Char = 8407
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
End Sub
```

My advice is to record macros and then change it...

Comment: Isn't OMaths the automation object for MS's equation editor? The OP asked about MathType.